# Determine whether the mouse is over a control? (over a Control pixel range)

Tags: .net, vb.net, mouse, bounds, mouse-position

I'm trying to write a function that should determine whether the mouse is over a range in pixels (the pixel range of a specific Control)

The problem is that the function only works for the bounds of the `Form`, don't work for buttons or any other control that I've tested ...what I'm missing?

```
''' <summary>
''' Determinates whether the mouse pointer is over a pixel range of the specified control.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="Control">The control.</param>
''' <returns>
''' <c>true</c> if mouse is inside the pixel range, <c>false</c> otherwise.
''' </returns>
Private Function MouseIsOverControl(ByVal [Control] As Control) As Boolean

    Return [Control].Bounds.Contains(MousePosition)

End Function
```

PS: I know the usage of the Mouse events, but this function is for generic usage.

Comment: `Return [Control].ClientRectangle.Contains([Control].PointToClient(MousePosition))`

Comment: @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå Thankyou but seems that is not very efficient because for example I need to put the mose around +10 pixels over a Picturebox to return a "True", If I put the mouse near a picturebox corner I get "False", also if I try to know if the mouse is over a button always I get "False" (When should be true).

Comment: FYI: I edited the comment. `Me.PointToClient` to `[Control].PointToClient`.

Comment: @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå Please post it in an answer if you want to mark it as accepted, you've solved my problem, thanks again. PS: Sorry for my English

Comment: Done! No problem! And sorry for mine:P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to transform the [MousePosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition(v=vs.110).aspx) into client coordinates and test the [ClientRectangle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientrectangle(v=vs.110).aspx) of the control.

<sub>VB.NET</sub>

```vb
Imports System.Windows.Forms
```

```
Public Function MouseIsOverControl(ByVal c As Control) As Boolean
    Return c.ClientRectangle.Contains(c.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition))
End Function
```

<sub>C#</sub>

```cs
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

```
public bool MouseIsOverControl(Control c)
{
    return c.ClientRectangle.Contains(c.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition));
}
```